# Cox proportional hazards for all pairwise comparisons

Tags: r, survival, cox-model

I am using Cox Proportional Hazards models (R survival and survminer packages) to test for effects of two categorical variables on survival: Treatment and Gender. One of those categorical variables, treatment, is not binary, as there were multiple treatments (for example: NoTx, Tx1, Tx2, Tx3). Thus far I have set the NoTx as the reference, and the CoxPH model tells me whether or not there are differences between each treatment and the no-treatment group--Great! However, we are also interested in survival differences AMONG all of the treatment groups (i.e., Tx1 VS Tx2, Tx2 vs Tx3, and Tx1 VS Tx3). I can obviously set each treatment as the reference by re-leveling the factor variable and re-running the model, but my concern there is that I will then be doing some of the same comparisons multiple times (e.g., NoTx VS Tx1... and later Tx1 vs NoTx). I'm also not sure if I would need to explicitly adjust for multiple testing in this scenario. So I'm wondering if there is a better way to resolve all of the pairwise comparisons while using a Cox PH model? Or is this something that would be easier to accomplish using a different survival model if I were to drop the other variable in the analysis?

Thanks for your time!